# Question in regards to representing propositons with P/~P

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In a standard Frege-System does it break any rules to have 'P' stand for, say "Smith is not president"?

Is it mandatory that such a statement be represented by '~P', or can it indeed be represented by 'P'?

Comment: You can propositional variables to represent any statements, even ones which in natural language contain negations. It's a matter of convenience.

Comment: Can ~P be used to represent a statement without a negation?

Comment: What I said in the first comment covers that. It follows that yes, $\neg P$  could be used to represent a statement without negation, and then $P$ would represent the negation of that statement. If you used $P$ to represent "Smith is not president", then $\neg P$ would represent the statement-without-negation "Smith is president".